# CollectionViewDelegate method doesn't get called after Swift 3 migration

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I have a simple collection view in my app, and I use the delegate to get notified when a cell was tapped, so I implement didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method. In Swift 2 this method's signature looked like this:

```
@objc func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

After running thru migration process this signature changed to this:

```
@objc func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

The compiler was happy and I moved on, but now this method doesn't get triggered when I tap any cell. I found a way to fix it:

```
@objc(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Obviously, the problem was in the first parameter name, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work without specifying obj-c selector explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to write @objc,

Here is a working code,

```
extension YourViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelect")
    }
}
```

Comment: My implementation was in extension too, but protocol conformance was in view controller declaration. Compiler gave me error like this "Objective-C method 'collectionView:didSelectItemAt:' provided by method 'collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)' does not match the requirement's selector ('collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:')". When I moved protocol conformance to extension everything worked like a charm. Stil don't quite understand what was wrong here, guess I need to read more about swift and obj-c interoperability.

Comment: Zaid why does it not requires @objc if we move the code to an extension?

Comment: @Ishika Extension is added only for view only purpose. The main issue wit OP's code was, he had wrong method declaration format.

Comment: Okay..Thanks Zaid

Answer (score 0):

add delegate in viewdidload also add uicollectionviewdelegae,uicollectionviewdatasource also in storyboard,

this helps me.